# Get focused element on mouse cursor move using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click any block it adds a new class `.is-selected`. It works fine when I get focus by click on the blocks. But It does not work when I use the **arrow keys** to get focus on another block. How can I get this focus when I use arrow keys?

```js
let getBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");

getBlocks.forEach((single) => {
  single.addEventListener("focus", () => {
    //remove all activated class
    getBlocks.forEach((x) => {
      x.classList.remove("is-selected");
    });
    
    //add the class to this new focus block
    single.classList.add("is-selected");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.root {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
.root:focus,
.block:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.is-selected {
  background-color: #f4f8ff !important;
  border: 1px solid #deebff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="root" contenteditable>
  <p name="jYdi0" class="block" tabindex="0">1</p>
  <p name="Hdy89" class="block" tabindex="0">2</p>
  <p name="wEldk" class="block" tabindex="0">3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED :**

```js
var ind = 0;

let getBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");

function caretInfo(up = true) {
  let sel = window.getSelection();
  let offset = sel.focusOffset;
  if (up) {
    sel.modify("move", "backward", "character");
    if (offset == sel.focusOffset) return true;
    else {
      sel.modify("move", "forward", "character");
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    sel.modify("move", "forward", "character");
    if (offset == sel.focusOffset) return true;
    else {
      sel.modify("move", "backward", "character");
      return false;
    }
  }
}

function selection(item) {
  getBlocks.forEach((x, index) => {
    if (x === item) {
      ind = index;
    }
    x.classList.remove("is-selected");
  });

  //add the class to this new focus block
  item.classList.add("is-selected");

}

getBlocks.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    selection(item);
  });
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  let change = false;
  if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38 && ind > 0) {
      change = caretInfo();
      if (change) {
        ind--;
      }
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40 && ind < document.querySelectorAll('.root p').length - 1) {
      change = caretInfo(false);
      if (change) {
        ind++;
      }
    }

    if (change) {
      let cur = document.querySelectorAll('.root p')[ind];
      cur.focus();
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.root {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.root:focus,
.block:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.is-selected {
  background-color: #f4f8ff !important;
  border: 1px solid #deebff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <p name="jYdi0" class="block" tabindex="0" contenteditable>1</p>
  <p name="Hdy89" class="block" tabindex="0" contenteditable>It was single line but now it's multiple line Just amazine what can be happen here. Here is the problem try to click "me" and then press arrow up. Ops :( but it should be on the first line</p>
  <p name="wEldk" class="block" tabindex="0" contenteditable>lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it has 2 bugs. 

1) If I click on block 3 and then use the arrow up key, it should append the class on block 2. But it does not

2) If I have multiple lines in any block, then it does not work properly. See my edited question for this problem

Comment: @Md.Tahazzot I have updated the code. I have reduced the code, and the bugs have been taken care of. Sorry for earlier. :)

Comment: This is a cool answer. But have one bug. If I have multiple lines on a block and the cursor is in the second line. Then by pressing the ```arrow up``` key it just focuses the previous block but it should just jump to line 1. You got the idea, right? https://imgur.com/a/LJC4ppM

Comment: @Md.Tahazzot please check the updated code. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like

```
   document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
       if(event.which === someEventCode) {
         // your code here
       }
    })
```

Here, the `someEventCode` variable is different for different key presses.